# Ubuntu SDK: No private key file given

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I've just installed ubuntu-sdk to play with it. When I'm creating a new project with qmake I always get this error "Application failed to start: No private key file given" (screeshot attached), always I tap the run button with the kit "ubuntusdk for desktop". If I connect my ubuntu phone, the app runs on the phone. But, I want to build it for desktop aswell.

[image]